# Show connection among multiple entity using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve tableau like UI on my page. Basically on page I have list of database table & user can select table to establish relationship with drag/drop & clicking on line which connects tables.

I am not sure what is the correct term & js framework help me to achieve that. for ref. I am attaching sample UI I have on Tableau. Here on picture i have 4 table where I can click on line for further operation.

[image]

Following are sample end result I am trying to achieve.
[image: cae1]

[image: case2]

Comment: this could help you https://github.com/uber/react-digraph

Comment: Can this work with vue? my app is built upon vuejs

Comment: no it doesn't it was built for react.